# Setting up a load balancer using Apache 2.4

Tags: load-balancing, apache-2.4, apache-2.2

I'm trying to setup a load balancer with Apache 2.4 but I can't make it work.

Here's what I wrote in my **http.conf** file:

```
<Proxy balancer://pop>
    BalancerMember http://pop1.local/ loadfactor=1
    BalancerMember http://pop2.local/ loadfactor=1
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
```

And this is the list of loaded Apache modules:

> core mod_so http_core event mod_authn_file mod_authn_core
>   mod_authz_host mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_user mod_authz_core
>   mod_access_compat mod_auth_basic mod_watchdog mod_reqtimeout
>   mod_filter mod_mime mod_log_config mod_env mod_headers mod_setenvif
>   mod_version mod_proxy mod_proxy_connect mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http
>   mod_proxy_fcgi mod_proxy_scgi mod_proxy_wstunnel mod_proxy_ajp
>   mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_express mod_slotmem_shm
>   mod_lbmethod_byrequests mod_lbmethod_bytraffic mod_lbmethod_bybusyness
>   mod_lbmethod_heartbeat mod_unixd mod_heartmonitor mod_status
>   mod_autoindex mod_dir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_php5

To test, I've setup three **VMs**, one for load balancer and two for back-end webservers. Using **hosts** file I introduced three domains in all of the machines:

```
192.168.0.100   pop.local
192.168.0.101   pop1.local
192.168.0.102   pop2.local
```

`pop.local` is my load balancer and other two are the back-ends. Having a `info.php` file created on each of the back-ends, I can load them entering `http://pop1.local/info.php` and `http://pop2.local`. But when I type `http://pop.local`, a `404 File not found` error returns.

The Apache on `pop.local` loads normally as if there's no `Proxy balancer` is set. It can even serve its own local files without a problem.

What's the problem? Am I missing something?

**[UPDATE]**

Here's the contents of my log file:

**error_log:**

```
[Wed Oct 02 02:40:55.530051 2013] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2179:tid 140142625933120] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Oct 02 02:40:55.541737 2013] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2179:tid 140142625933120] AH00489: Apache/2.4.6 (Unix) PHP/5.5.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 02 02:40:55.541768 2013] [core:notice] [pid 2179:tid 140142625933120] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd'
[Wed Oct 02 02:42:04.170782 2013] [:error] [pid 2615:tid 140142199158528] [client 192.168.0.81:55732] script '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: I'll update the question.

Comment: What's up with the negative vote!?

Comment: Which of the servers was the logfile from?

Comment: The log content belongs to the balancer. I've made sure that the request does not arrive at the back-ends by removing `access_log` and `error_log` files in them and sending a new request. No log file was created for the new request.

Comment: I'm missing the `ProxyPass` line in your config.

Comment: This is my first time setting up a load balancer. Is it OK to add `ProxyPass / balander://pop`?

Comment: Having the `ProxyPass / balander://pop` added, now `error_log` says: `No protocol handler was valid for the URL /info.php. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.` with a `500 Internal server` error on browser.

Comment: You should try haproxy for load balancing it's easy to configure and have great functionality.

Comment: Unless `balander` is a typo this may be your problem (in that it should be balan*c*er :-)

Comment: The issue you mentioned was real but even with `ProxyPass / balancer://pop` I still get `If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.` error. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Is `mod_proxy_html` needed? Because I don't have that and since I've compiled the Apache myself, it's not that easy to compile a new module. I just hope the lack of this module is not the case!

Comment: I fixed it, it should have been `ProxyPass / balancer://pop/` with the slash at the end!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete balancer config that should work:

```
<Proxy balancer://pop>
    BalancerMember http://pop1.local/ loadfactor=1
    BalancerMember http://pop2.local/ loadfactor=1
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://pop/
```

As stated in [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), if the first part of `ProxyPass` ends with a `/` the second part also needs to end with the `/`:

> If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument
>   should also end with a trailing / and vice versa. Otherwise the
>   resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do
>   not deliver the expected results.

You also need to make sure that `ProxyRequests` is set to `off`.

Comment: Just don't forget the `/` at the end of `ProxyPass`. Thanks again.